# Apparent Difference between GLM Quaternion-Euler conversion and the one shown in Wikipedia/EuclideanSpace websites

Tags: math, glm-math

So the GLM definition for converting a quaternion to an Euler "Pitch" angle is:

```
atan(T(2) * (q.y * q.z + q.w * q.x), q.w * q.w - q.x * q.x - q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z)
```

With T a typename.  Contrast this with that shown in, for example, the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles):

```
asin((-2) * (q.x * q.z - q.w * q.y))
```

Which so happens to be what GLM calls "Yaw".  This is confusing enough in itself, but I can accept different naming conventions.  But when we look at the GLM definition for pitch, it doesn't match ANY of the Quaternion->Euler conversions given on wikipedia (or on the [euclideanspace](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/) website).  What is the reason behind this?  is it because GLM is trying to somehow make up for the fact that they are not (for whatever reason) using atan2?  Also, please do comment if this is better suited for the Maths stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised just now that the definitions do, indeed, match up, when you consider that for a unit quaternion:

```
q.x * q.x + q.y * q.y + q.z * q.z + q.w * q.w = 1
```

which sorts everything out.  I still don't know why GLM would avoid using the "1 - 2(...)" equations though.